# -infinity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm transforming postgres db into ms sql db. Some my records have value "-infinity" for timestamp without timezone column. I would like to transform it to "0001-01-01 00:00:00" or to null. But I can not even preview data in ADF. When I just call table I get the next error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 10) (vm-4a714624 executor 1): java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:892)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.millisToMicros(DateTimeUtils.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.fromJavaTimestamp(DateTimeUtils.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$13(JdbcUtils.scala:450)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$13$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:447)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:352)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:334)
at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:762)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:155)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:498)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:501)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

[image]

Any ideas how to deal with "-infinity" in ADF?

Answer (score 0):

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (vm-b4791957 executor 1): java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
```

The '-infinite' value exceeds the maximum value that a long can represent. This may be the reason for getting the value while previewing the data.
You can use the following query to transform the -infinite value column to a null value instead of selecting the table in the source:

```
SELECT
    id,
    NULLIF(<columnName>, '-infinity')::timestamptz AS transformed_timestamp
FROM <tableName>
```

[image]

After this, you will be able to get a data preview as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there any way to transform '-infinity' into null in destination database?

Comment: Alternate way is you need to update the column which is having '-infinity' in database itself using command
UPDATE <TableName>
SET <columName> = 'Null'
WHERE <columnName> = '-infinity';